# substring in R with stringr

Tags: r, string, substring

I have a string that looks like this :

```
my_sting="AC=1;AN=249706;AF=4.00471e-06;rf_tp_probability=8.55653e-01;"
```

it is based on a column in my data :

[image]

```
  REF ALT    QUAL FILTER  INFO
1   C   A 3817.77   PASS  AN=2;AF=4.00471e06;rf_tp_probability=8.55653
2   C   G 3817.77   PASS  AN=3;AF=5;rf_tp_probability=8.55653
```

i wish to select only the part that start with AF= and ends with the number AF is equal to .
for example here: AF=4.00471e-06

I tried this :

```
print(str_extract_all(my_sting, "AF=.+;"))
[[1]]
[1] "AF=4.00471e-06;rf_tp_probability=8.55653e-01;"
```

but it returned everything until the end. instead of returning AF=4.00471e-06
is there any way to fix this ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can write the pattern using a negated character class `[^;]+` as:

```
library(stringr)
my_sting="AC=1;AN=249706;AF=4.00471e-06;rf_tp_probability=8.55653e-01;"
print(str_extract_all(my_sting, "AF=[^;]+"))
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[1] "AF=4.00471e-06"
```

Comment: i tried data_snp_1$AF_total=as.character(str_extract_all(data_snp_1$INFO, "AF_amr=[^;]+")) and dot a vector which repets the result c("AF_amr=0.00000e+00", "AF_amr=0.00000e+00", "AF_amr=0)

Comment: @ElizaRomanski if you want a single value use str_extract like [this example](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyczqSixqFKjuKQoMy@9SJMrtzK@uATItFVydLY1tHb0szUysTQ3MLN2dLM10TMwMDE3TNUFcovS4ksK4guK8pMSkzJzMksqbS30TE3NTI2BsobWSlwFQPNKQMbGp1aUFCUml2jATNZRUAKaFR1nHautpKn5/z8A)

Comment: four bird - editted the QA

Comment: @ElizaRomanski You can see here that you are still getting all the matches https://regex101.com/r/GCko6U/1 Is that not the expected result? What do you want as the result?

Comment: @ElizaRomanski If you only want the values `(?<=AF=)[^;]+` See https://regex101.com/r/QBuyH3/1 and see [this example](https://tio.run/##dY9PC4JAFMTvfoqHJ6UQ/20KtsQSGoJYqZ2iFg0LYStZ95CffluhbjUwMAy8H/O4lKxreM1HYxC8e9y4qd1HOggVsQ5QxAmQrAKl/YFkkKRZFRcAaZ5sNUe1a2UCXugEVhCovCNlqZocuxFJsG/Zth84rb2I@JWKnvb82dRNxzox4tBCaIE8zf1gNr8w3oRB/691rVezxbSeti/B64ugNWPG94k56MZqiRXEPJ6j00w3TSnf)

Answer (score 1):

Another option. Use  "followed by ;" (i.e., `(?=;)`)

```r
my_sting="AC=1;AN=249706;AF=4.00471e-06;rf_tp_probability=8.55653e-01;"

str_extract(my_sting, "AF=.*?(?=;)")
#> [1] "AF=4.00471e-06"
```